# XML get nodes name through xPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have this XML

```
<Parent>
 <Children>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <secondchild>2</secondchild>
  <child3>3</child3>
  <fourth>4</fourth>
 </Children>
</Parent>
```

using xpath, i want to get each `Children`'s node **name** to end up with :

- child1
- secondhild
- child3
- fourth

something like `Parent/Children/*[@name]`
.. without aiming at any attribute, only the main child node name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
<?php
$string = '<Parent>
 <Children>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <secondchild>2</secondchild>
  <child3>3</child3>
  <fourth>4</fourth>
 </Children>
</Parent>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$children = $xml->xpath('/Parent/Children/*');

foreach ($children as $child){
    echo $child->getName() . "\n";
}
```

or

```
<?php
$string = '<Parent>
 <Children>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <secondchild>2</secondchild>
  <child3>3</child3>
  <fourth>4</fourth>
 </Children>
</Parent>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$children = $xml->xpath('/Parent/Children/*');
$result = array();

foreach ($children as $child){
    $result[] = $child->getName();
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPATH:

```
Parent/Children/*/name()
```

This calls the name() function on the resulting nodes.